# What is the expected value of the number of circles formed?

Tags: probability

There are $99$ identical square tiles, each with a quarter-circle drawn on it. When the tiles are randomly arranged in a $9$ by $11$ rectangle, what is the expected value of the number of full circles formed?

Comment: This is the third very similar question you post today without any personal input, whose solution is a direct application of the linearity of expectation. Let me at least hope that you begin to discern a pattern...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume tiles can be rotated, but can't be turned over (which would hide the quarter-circle).

Hint 1: A full circle is formed at any of the $80$ interior vertices if the four tiles touching that vertex all have the proper orientation.  What is the probability of that?

Hint 2: Expected value of sum = sum of expected values.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: But if a circle is formed at a given vertex, the neihgbouring vertices can not have circles, so the events are not independent.

Comment: @TonioElGringo: True, but [expected values of dependent events are still additive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Answer (score 0):

lets match each formed circle to its upper left corner,
there are 8x10 such upper left tiles possible,
the probability for each of those tiles to form a circle:

$ P($tile $i$ formed a circle and is in the upper left corner$)= (\frac14)^4 $

(each tile of the 4 has a 1/4 chance of being in the right oriantation)

therefore
$E[X] = E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i]= 8\cdot 10 \cdot (\frac14)^4$